# not getting session variables on second page while hosting my website (On localhost, it works)

Tags: php, session

Down, in the second page i am not getting the session variable values. Actually sessions variables are not recieving in second file(index.php).

Error is Notice: Undefined index: userid in /storage/ssd5/520/5088520/public_html/index.php on line 150

1 - login.php //file 1

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['login'] )) 
    {
      $_SESSION["userid"] = $_POST["userid"];
      $_SESSION["user"] = $_POST["user"]; 

      $userid=$_SESSION["userid"];
      $user=$_SESSION["user"];

      if ($userid=='' || $user=='') 
      {
        //generate error
        echo 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

        renderForm();
       }
       else
       {
         //query
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id='$userid' 
         AND user='$user'") or die(mysql_error());

         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

         if ($row['user_id'] == 1 || $row['user_id'] == 2) 
         {
           $_SESSION['login_status'] = true;
           echo "<script> window.open ('index.php','_self') </script>";
          }
          else
          {
            echo "Sorry, No account exist";
          }   
       }
    }
    //if submit button not pressed yet. show form:
    else
    {
      //now show form
      renderForm();
    }


    //redenring form
    <?php
       //function starts 
       function renderForm()
       {
    ?>
         <form role="form" method="post">
           <input placeholder="User ID" name="userid" type="text">
           <input placeholder="User" name="user" type="text">

            <button type="submit" name="login">Login</a>                            
          </form>
    <?php
       }  //function ends
    ?>
```

Second file where error comes

2-index.php  //file 2

```
<?php    
       session_start();

       if ($_SESSION['login_status']==false)    {
          header("Location:login.php");    }    else    { ?> <body>   //somewhere inside here i am accessing the session variables  <?php
        if ($_SESSION['userid']==1) //line 150
        {
          echo "<a class='navbar-brand' href='index.php'>Admin</a>";
        }
        if ($_SESSION['userid']==2 ) 
        {
         echo "<a class='navbar-brand' href='index.php'>Clerk</a>";
        }  ?> </body>
```

on local host. this code runs . But i am now hosting it. but i am not understanding, what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Declare session_start(); on second page.

Comment: Are any session functions available? Try var_dump($_SESSION);

Comment: can u plz more elaborate. i m just a newbie. where to use var_dump($_SESSION); ?

Comment: Just add var_dump($_SESSION); after the session_start(); it should show you all session variable. After that echo your created session variables on the first page to test

Comment: Make sure the session id is the same on both pages.
<code>echo session_id();</code>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start();` at the top of the second file in order to access session variables in it.
Add `session_start();` in every page you are accessing session variables from otherwise it doesn't work. It is a requirement to start the session in order to access the super global variable `$_SESSION`.

**Edit:**

> You need to use `if( !isset($_SESSION['userid']) )` instead of
>   `if ($_SESSION['userid']==1)` on the `index.php` page.
>   Otherwise, it will throw you `undefined index` error if you are
>   visiting the `index.php` before attempting to log in.

You may have noticed that your code doesn't throw error if you visit `index.php` after logging in.

Comment: yes i have tried. but still not working. i have declared session_start() on top of both files.

Comment: the only issue is not getting session values on other files.

Comment: bro i m accessing through login page. not directly. but still the same error.

Comment: Are you accessing it after submitting the log in form?

Comment: yes i m accessing after the login form. but snot able to get the session variables on 2nd page. on local host.it works. i m hosting my site online